# JSF/PrimeFaces - Template with <p:layout>

Tags: templates, jsf, layout, primefaces, facelets

I need to create a layout like [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutFull.jsf) but with all the containers on separated files, like:

**top.xhtml**

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" header="#{support.applicationTitle}">
            <h:form>
                <p:menubar>
                    <p:menuitem value="Quit" icon="ui-icon-close" action="#{userController.logOut()}" />
                </p:menubar>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
```

Without the `</p:layout>` because it will be close on my **footer.xhtml** like:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="south" header="© 2012 - 2012 PORTAL DE IDEIAS">
</p:layoutUnit></p:layout>
```

I have tried with both files but I get a error telling me that I need to close the *layout* tag, what is correct, but how can I solve my problem? Is this the best approach for a template? And another problem is that the *layout* tag require a center *layoutUnit*

Comment: Update: `<p:layout>` is no more available, so now this question is obsolete.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is indeed not the right approach. Your template has to be XML well formed. I suggest to create a master template file instead if all you want is to only specify the center unit.

Taking the example on the showcase site, that should look like this:

`/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
    <h:head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Top" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:outputText value="Top unit content." />
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" header="Bottom" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:outputText value="South unit content." />
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Left" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:form>
                    <ui:include src="../templates/themeMenu.xhtml" />
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" header="Right" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" effect="drop">
                <h:outputText value="Right unit content." />
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <ui:insert name="content">Put default content here, if any.</ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Note the `<ui:insert>` in the center unit.

The template client can then just look like this:

`/page.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
     <ui:define name="content">
         <p>Here goes your view-specific content.</p>
     </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

which you open by http://example.com/contextname/page.xhtml.

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

If you're looking for live open source examples of advanced Facelets templating, you may find [OmniFaces showcase app](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase) useful.